# async await js - резудьтат функции undefined через return (JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, async-await, promise

у меня возникла проблема вывода ассинхронных данных. Можете помочь и обьяснить, как вывести хоть какойто ответ кроме undefined из функции emailValid, поидее в переменной **emailAfter**  и **usernameAfter** должен быть **promise** (так как возвращаеться promise через *return* и *await* ждет ответа из MongoDB), а ответ получаеться **undefined**, почему и есть идеи по исправлению ?

Заранее спасибо

```
function emailValid(){
        db.collection("userData").find({
            email: clientData.email
        },{username: 1, email: 1})
        .toArray((err, result) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                if (result.length == 0) {
                    resolve("Email is valid");
                } else{
                    reject(new Error("Email is already taken"));
                }
            }); 
        });

function usernameValid(){
        db.collection("userData").find({
            username: clientData.username
        },{username: 1, email: 1})
        .toArray((err, result) => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                if (result.length == 0) {
                    resolve("Username is valid");
                } else{
                    reject(new Error("Username is already taken"));
                }
            }); 
        });
    }

async function validationReg(){
        // Email validation
        try{
            let emailAfter = await emailValid(); // emailAfter  - undefined

            let usernameAfter = await usernameValid(); // usernameAfter - undefined

            if (emailAfter == usernameAfter) {
                res.status(201).json({
                    message: "Data Valid",
                    emailAfter: emailAfter,
                    usernameAfter: usernameAfter
                })
            }
        } catch(err) {
            err = err.toString();
            res.status(203).json({
                message: "Error",
                err: err
            })
        }
```

Comment: "почему"(с), да потому что функции ничего не возвращают. `return new Promise` должен окружать все тело функций.

Comment: Alexander, спасибо за ваш комментарий, заметил данную погрешность через 20 мин после отправки,  ответ выше помог решить "логическую" часть проблемы

Comment: Yugofx, Спасибо за помошь !! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов, один из них вам уже написали в комментарии. Верните из `usernameValid` и `emailValid` промисы и резолвьте их в `validationReg`.

```
function emailValid() {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        db.collection("userData")
            .find(
                { email: clientData.email },
                { username: 1, email: 1 }
            )
            .toArray((err, result) => {
                result.length == 0
                    && res("Email is valid")
                    || rej("Email is already taken");
            })
    });
}
```

Аналогично для второй.

Или есть вариант не создавать промисы в каждой функции, а биндить их уже в самой `validationReg`.

```
function emailValid(res, rej) {
    db.collection("userData")
        .find(
            { email: clientData.email },
            { username: 1, email: 1 }
        )
        .toArray((err, result) => {
            result.length == 0
                 && res("Email is valid")
                 || rej("Email is already taken");
        })
}

...

async function validationReg(){
    try {
        let emailAfter = await new Promise(emailValid);
        let usernameAfter = await new Promise(usernameValid);
        ...
    } catch(err) {
        ...
    }
}
```